# Running unit tests under Chess

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest, chess

When trying to run my unit test under [Chess](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/chess/), it get the following error:

> Hosting rules specify that the test
>   type 'Unit Test' cannot run in the
>   host adapter 'Chess'. To run this test
>   in 'Chess', change the hosting rules.
>   To use the default test host for tests
>   that cannot be run in the specified
>   host adapter, change the test run
>   configuration settings.

The test method is defined like so:

```
[TestMethod]  
[HostType("Chess")]  
[TestProperty("ChessDebug", "true")]  
public void MyUnitTest()  
{...}
```

In the localtestrun.testrunconfig file I have the following settings:

Hosts > Run in default host with the Microsoft.ManagedChess.TeamTestHost.MasterHostAdapter selected.

Any ideas as to what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted Visual Studio and changed the options in localtestrun.testrunconfig to 
Hosts > Run in default host with the default host type.

Answer (score 1):

I know it was some time ago, but O'm very interested in getting and using Chess iwith my Unit Tests, I'm using the Visual Studio 2010 version which is available on code plex and it compiles and appears to work okay.

I'm trying to get it to work with my Unit Test in the sample projects, but I'm now getting in the output window:

"The host type 'Chess' cannot be loaded for the following reason: The key 'Chess' cannot be found. The test 'NoConsumer' will run in the default host."

Any ideas.

Also are you still using Chess, if not why not?